# Jquery - how to make this code work? (extracting info from another website)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found nice piece of code that seems to work, but I have difficulites to adapt it to my needs (never used Jquery, just very basics of Java). 
I was able to figure out a part of it, but haven't succeed to make it work.

The website I'm trying to extract info from: [HERE](http://rycerzeiksiezniczki.pl/kids/agatka/?lang=pl). I want to access the value of child (h2) present in div class="cash" (the amount of money raised).

I'm trying to adapt this code ([jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTUx5/)):

```
var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://stackoverflow.com/\' and xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]//h3//a\'&format=json&callback=?';

$.getJSON( url, function(data){
    $.getJSON( url, function(data){
        $.each(data.query.results.a, function(){   
            $('body').append('<div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com'+this.href +'">'+this.content+'</a></div>')   
        })
    console.dir(data.query.results)
})
```

I've changed the url into:

```
var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://rycerzeiksiezniczki.pl/kids/agatka/?lang=pl' and xpath=\'//div[@class="cash"]//h2\'&format=json&callback=?';
```

(replaced website URL and xpath).
Played also with the rest of the code (url, and this.stuff), but no success ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqgvkmkm/)).

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: What are you seeing in the error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you escaped the URL string wrong: 
`'..../?lang=pl'...` --> `'..../?lang=pl\'...`

The `'` after the lang query parameter should be escaped like `\'`.

Additional your xpath query is not precise enough: This should work:

```
var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://rycerzeiksiezniczki.pl/kids/agatka/?lang=pl\' and xpath=\'//div[@class="row cash"]//h2\'&format=json&callback=?';


$.getJSON( url, function(data){
    $.each(data.query.results, function(){  

        $('body').append('<div><a href="http://rycerzeiksiezniczki.pl/kids/agatka/?lang=pl'+'">'+this.content+' ' + this.strong + '</a></div>')          
     })

})
```

The tag you want to extract contains the classes row **and** cash.

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved. I'll definitely spend some time on JQuery, it seems to be pretty useful thing! Also, I'm really grateful for the explanation and not just simply posting the code, most probably I'd miss the escape character, whereas now I know where I should place some extra attention.